# Concatenating in Visual Fox Pro 6.0

Tags: concatenation, visual-foxpro

I have 8 old files that have very outdated fields. I need to concatenate the three existing fields (areacode, prefix, and suffix) into one new field telephone.  After that is done, I can delete the three old fields in table designer. Have a manual in front of me but nothing says concat or concatenate.

```
 areacode      prefix     suffix    telephone
    702          555       1324     7025551324
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

REPLACE telephone WITH ALLTRIM(areacode) + ALLTRIM(prefix) + ALLTRIM(suffix) ALL

LAK was close but the scope needed to be specified.

Answer (score 5):

REPLACE ALL telephone WITH ALLTRIM(areacode) + ALLTRIM(prefix) + ALLTRIM(suffix)

This will do it.  String concatenation just uses the plus sign. (Obviously change it to suit the order of fields you want, any validation you want, etc).

Comment: It says 1 replacement and has no effect.